# compare dates in mysql where the day, month and year are stored separately

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to compare several entries, for which I have the day, month and year saved in separate variables. When I try the following, I do not get the right answer:

```
    $rescount=mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `sdcheckings` WHERE  `dchecked` = 1 AND  `email` ="'.$_SESSION['email'].'" AND  `cday` >'.date('j').' AND  `cmonth` >='.date('n').' AND  `cyear` >='.date('Y'));
```

The reason is that this would ignore and entry that is in the following month, but that has a smaller day number.
What would be the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: You can use MYSQL function [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Anyway, I don't understand what is your comparison criteria: is current date (as it seems from your example) or a variable date?

Comment: I want to compare previous entries to today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use `CONCAT_WS` to create date in query

```
DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',cyear,cmonth,cdate)) AS date
```

Then you got date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format to compare

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works now, thanks!

```
    $rescount=mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `sdcheckings` WHERE  `dchecked` = 1 AND  `email` ="'.$_SESSION['email'].'" AND  DATE(CONCAT_WS("-",`cyear`,`cmonth`,`cday`)) > CURDATE()');
```